# How can I get multiple images and upload them in a folder in Laravel API?

Tags: laravel, api

The code below uses `file_get_contents('php://input')` to upload a single image, but it is not working in the case of multiple images; it is not working.

```
// Function to upload images by PUT method
function addMultiImagesPut(Request $req)
{
    $images = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $filename = 'piyush-'.time().'.jpeg';
    $path = public_path('screenshots').'/'.$filename;

    file_put_contents($path, $images);

    $result['status'] = '200';
    $result['errors'] = "";
    $result['msg'] = 'Images uploaded Successfully';

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: can you please clear that in $images = file_get_contents('php://input'); you will get multiple images response ?

Comment: Yes i am getting raw post data from here.

Comment: Its a laravel API, which simply uploads a single image. but when we send multiple images as raw Post data its not working. i need to save 2 images in different folders

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting array from raw post data then you can solve it using foreach loop like below code :

```
function addMultiImagesPut(Request $req)
{
   $result = [];
   $images = file_get_contents('php://input');
   
   foreach ($images as $image)
   {
     $filename = 'piyush-'.time().'.jpeg';

     $path = public_path('screenshots').'/'.$filename;

     file_put_contents($path,$image);

     $result['status'] = '200';

     $result['errors'] = "";

     $result['msg'] = 'Images uploaded Successfully';
   }
   return  $result; 
}
```

Code is not tested but it might be work like above logic.
Hope this code will help you. :)

Comment: No, I am getting an Encoded string.. which has boundries like .... --Boundary-D13FC27B-A191-4BA3-824F-5FBEA9E68D81
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="screenshot"; filename="imagename.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Comment: Still, i am trying your code .. in case ..

Comment: No, Your code is not working-- i need to know how can i splt encoded images data separated by boundries like --Boundary-D13FC27B-A191-4BA3-824F-5FBEA9E68D81
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="screenshot"; filename="imagename.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

and upload them to my folder..

Comment: can you please try : $filestring = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $filearray = explode("\n", $filestring);

    while (list($var, $val) = each($filearray)) {
        ++$var;
        $val = trim($val);
        print "Line $var: $val<br />";
    }

Comment: Also you can try using : http_build_query base code. it will be help you I am damn sure.

Comment: Sorry still not working